# How to Modify Chapter number and Chapter title style in TOC by using kaobook.cls?

Tags: table-of-contents, kaobook

My tags are follows:

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\PreventPackageFromLoading{amssymb}

\documentclass[%
    fontsize=10pt, 
    twoside=true, 
    open=any, 
    chapterentrydots=true, 
    numbers=noenddot 
]{kaobook}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Test}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Trial}
\end{document}
```

It produced the output as:

[image]

In this, I need to get the total block for `Chapter`, in `bold and Cyan color` and `Chapter number` in `14pt` and `Chapter title is in 11pt`, refer the below screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: [kaobook](https://github.com/fmarotta/kaobook/blob/master/kaobook.cls) is based on KOMA-Script, so you can use the KOMA styling commands for the ToC

Comment: I'm a beginner in koma, can you help me to achieve the requirements please